# Match consecutive list of exactly one character in set with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I don't think I'll even try to explain this, I don't know the words to, but I'd like to achieve the following:

Given a string like this:

```
+++>><<<--
```

I'd like a match to give me: `+++`, but also match if any of the other characters were in the string consecutively like they are. So if the `+++` wasn't there, I'd like to match `>>`.

I tried using the following regular expression:

```
([><\-\+]+)
```

However, given the string above, it would match the entire string, and not the first list of consecutive characters.

If it makes a difference, this is in Ruby (1.9.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the ruby bit, but you can do this with backreferences in the pattern:

```
(.)\1+
```

What this does is to use a capturing group `()` to capture any character `.` followed by any number `+` of the same character `\1`. The `\1` is a backreference to the the first captured group; in a pattern with more capturing groups `\2` would be the second captured group and so on.

**Java Example**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaabbccaa");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(0)); // prints "aaa"
```

**Ruby Example**

```
# Return an array of matched patterns.
string = '+++>><<<--'
string.scan( /((.)\2+)/ ).collect { |match| match.first }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! (I'll accept when time limit is up, sorry).

Comment: In Ruby, you might call `string = '+++>><<<--'; string.scan( /((.)\2+)/ ).collect { |match| match.first }` to return an array of matches.